# Which form of SVD is most commonly in stats/ML (e.g., PCA, least squares)?

Tags: least-squares, svd

SVM comes in several forms: e.g., the full form and the reduced forms https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Reduced_SVDs.

Is there one that is more commonly used in stats? If so, why is this particular form used more often than others?

I have seen it used for things like PCA and I've also seen SVD applied to least squares.

Comment: SVD usually is not used for least squares fitting: the Cholesky Decomposition is preferred.  Are you perhaps trying to ask a question about PCA?

Comment: @whuber I will edit my post to be more general than to restrain it to least squares, but I have seen SVD used before for least squares. Actually, I thought SVD and QR were more common for least squares than Cholesky because Cholesky isn't as numerically stable?

Comment: Sorry, I did mean to write QR for exactly that reason!  As Wikipedia points out, the full form of SVD isn't often used -- the extra information is superfluous because all it offers beyond the reduced SVD is an orthogonal basis for the kernel ("a full unitary decomposition of the null-space of the matrix").